# how can we get how many users have the answered same questionfrom

Tags: mysql

How can we find that how many users have the answered same choice as your choice in poll and how many questions are same in mysql query.
Here is my table on which i am running queries.

```
  id          questionid              answerid             userid
  1              1762                   3514                156        
  2              1761                   3512                156
  3              1760                   3511                156
  4              1759                   3509                156
  5              1762                   3514                157
  6              1761                   3513                157
  7              1760                   3510                157
  8              1759                   3509                157
  9              1762                   3514                158
 10              1761                   3512                158
 11              1760                   3511                158
 12              1759                   3509                158
```

i have tried

```
SELECT A.*
FROM sameanswers AS A
INNER JOIN (SELECT questionid, answerid
        FROM sameanswers
        GROUP BY questionid, answerid
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) as B
ON A.questionid = B.questionid AND A.answerid = B.answerid
```

And my expected output is how many users have same choice and on how many questions.
for example 2 users has same answer on 2 questions.

Comment: Please add example data, expected output and the query you tried.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want a list of all the questions someone has answered, and a count of others who have answered the same question with the same answer.

Crude way using a sub query:-

```
SELECT A.*, b.others_count
FROM sameanswers AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT questionid, answerid, COUNT(*) AS others_count
    FROM sameanswers
    WHERE userid != 156
    GROUP BY questionid, answerid
) as B
ON A.questionid = B.questionid AND A.answerid = B.answerid
WHERE A.userid = 156
```

or using a normal join:-

```
SELECT A.id, A.questionid, A.answerid, A.userid, COUNT(B.id)
FROM sameanswers AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN sameanswers AS B
ON A.questionid = B.questionid AND A.answerid = B.answerid AND A.userid != B.userid
WHERE A.userid = 156
GROUP BY A.id, A.questionid, A.answerid, A.userid;
```

SQL fiddle for these:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07670/9

EDIT - this should get your the results for you new requirement:-

```
SELECT B.userid, COUNT(B.id) AS match_count
FROM sameanswers AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN sameanswers AS B
ON A.questionid = B.questionid 
AND A.answerid = B.answerid 
AND A.userid != B.userid
WHERE A.userid = 156
GROUP BY B.userid
ORDER BY match_count DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: actually i want to display here the users which has maximum number of matching choice suppose there are there users a,b,c has they have taken a quiz and for user c we wants to display the number of user which has maximum number of same answer as user c

Comment: Added a suggestion for that.

Comment: SELECT count(samechoice) as total_user,samechoice FROM
(
 select sameanswers.userid, count(qau.sameanswerid) as samechoice
  from sameanswers Inner join
      sameanswers qau
         on qau.userid = 159 and
         qau.questionid = sameanswers.questionid and
         qau.answerid = sameanswers.answerid
         where sameanswers.userid!='159'
group by sameanswers.userid
order by samechoice desc
)b  group by samechoice
ORDER BY  samechoice desc limit 0,1    ,i have used this one and it works but thanks for your help really useful for me.